# Upgrade to Django 1.7 - AppRegistryNotReady exception

Tags: django, wsgi

I'm struggling by trying to make things work after upgrading the Django version from 1.6.7 to 1.7. It looks like I'm not able to focus on the right matter. I try to resume the situation so far.

Thing is: if I leave the command django.setup() in my wsgi.py file, when I try to access my website I get an internal server error (500). Looking at the logs, I get:

```
[Sun Oct 12 12:38:50 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] mod_wsgi (pid=23258): Target WSGI script '/home/thrasher/webapps/django/myproject.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Sun Oct 12 12:38:50 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] mod_wsgi (pid=23258): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/thrasher/webapps/django/myproject.wsgi'.
[Sun Oct 12 12:38:50 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sun Oct 12 12:38:50 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/thrasher/webapps/django/myproject.wsgi", line 16, in <module>
[Sun Oct 12 12:38:50 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     application = get_wsgi_application()
[Sun Oct 12 12:38:50 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/thrasher/webapps/django/lib/python2.7/django/core/wsgi.py", line 14, in get_wsgi_application
[Sun Oct 12 12:38:50 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     django.setup()
[Sun Oct 12 12:38:50 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/thrasher/webapps/django/lib/python2.7/django/__init__.py", line 21, in setup
[Sun Oct 12 12:38:50 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
[Sun Oct 12 12:38:50 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/thrasher/webapps/django/lib/python2.7/django/apps/registry.py", line 78, in populate
[Sun Oct 12 12:38:50 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     raise RuntimeError("populate() isn't reentrant")
[Sun Oct 12 12:38:50 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] RuntimeError: populate() isn't reentrant
```

However, if I comment the django.setup() call, trying to access the website gets me this stack trace:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://www.creepyvisions.it/

Django Version: 1.7
Python Version: 2.7.8
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.admin.apps.SimpleAdminConfig',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.admindocs',
 'myproject.archivio',
 'sorl.thumbnail',
 'django.contrib.sitemaps',
 'rest_framework')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/home/thrasher/webapps/django/lib/python2.7/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  98.                 resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
File "/home/thrasher/webapps/django/lib/python2.7/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  338.             for pattern in self.url_patterns:
File "/home/thrasher/webapps/django/lib/python2.7/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in url_patterns
  367.         patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
File "/home/thrasher/webapps/django/lib/python2.7/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in urlconf_module
  361.             self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py" in import_module
  37.     __import__(name)
File "/home/thrasher/webapps/django/myproject/urls.py" in <module>
  33.                        url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
File "/home/thrasher/webapps/django/lib/python2.7/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in urls
  260.         return self.get_urls(), self.app_name, self.name
File "/home/thrasher/webapps/django/lib/python2.7/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in get_urls
  221.             self.check_dependencies()
File "/home/thrasher/webapps/django/lib/python2.7/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in check_dependencies
  159.         if not apps.is_installed('django.contrib.admin'):
File "/home/thrasher/webapps/django/lib/python2.7/django/apps/registry.py" in is_installed
  223.         self.check_apps_ready()
File "/home/thrasher/webapps/django/lib/python2.7/django/apps/registry.py" in check_apps_ready
  124.             raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")

Exception Type: AppRegistryNotReady at /
Exception Value: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

For the sake of completion, this is the code related to wsgi:

myprojext.wsgi

```
import os
import sys

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myproject.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

wgsi.py

```
import django
from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler


def get_wsgi_application():
    #django.setup()
    return WSGIHandler()
```

Things look very odd to me, I performed a lot of searches in the official Django docs and in various forums, but I'm still unable to get things work properly. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you using `get_user_model()` anywhere in your code? Are you calling `django.setup()` anywhere else in your code?

Comment: Hi @KevinChristopherHenry, no, I'm not using those methods. It turned out that the problem was a duplication, in the INSTALLED_APPS, of the django.contrib.admin. It looks that it was the root of the problem. As soon as I removed the second reference, I uncommented django.setup()  in wsgi.py and things became sunny and clear again. Now everything is working fine.

Comment: @LucaTrifilio Please write this as an answer and then accept it.  Otherwise this question will continue to show up as an unanswered question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out that the problem was a duplication, in the INSTALLED_APPS, of the django.contrib.admin. It looks that it was the root of the problem. As soon as I removed the second reference, I uncommented django.setup() in wsgi.py and things became sunny and clear again. Now everything is working fine.