# Internal Server Error on Django after I changed database

Tags: python, mysql, django, web, sqlite

I recently started a Django project. I have been using the SQLite3 database so far for some testing, but now I would like to switch to MySQL. I configured the setting file and ran the first migration, everything went just fine, I checked in MySQL and the tables have been created successfully. I checked on my browser and it was okay there too.

Happy of the results I erase the SQLite3 file from the project folder and I suspected it wasn't being used no more. Well, it seems I was wrong: now when I try to reach my website via browser I get a Internal Server Error error message with no extra information (and yes, I have already `DEBUG = TRUE`, nothing change).

What could be the problem?

**EDIT 1**
Now with more code. This is the database part of my setting.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'XXX',
        'USER' : 'XXX',
        'PASSWORD' : 'XXX',
        'HOST' : '127.0.0.1',
    }
}
```

This is the Apache error log:

```
[Thu Sep 10 16:09:43.899538 2015] [:error] [pid 7503] [remote XXX] mod_wsgi (pid=7503): Target WSGI script 'XXX/api/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Thu Sep 10 16:09:43.899757 2015] [:error] [pid 7503] [remote XXX] mod_wsgi (pid=7503): Exception occurred processing WSGI script 'XXX/api/wsgi.py'.
[Thu Sep 10 16:09:43.899962 2015] [:error] [pid 7503] [remote XXX] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Thu Sep 10 16:09:43.900117 2015] [:error] [pid 7503] [remote XXX]   File "XXX/api/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
[Thu Sep 10 16:09:43.900423 2015] [:error] [pid 7503] [remote XXX]     application = get_wsgi_application()
[Thu Sep 10 16:09:43.900469 2015] [:error] [pid 7503] [remote XXX]   File "XXX/XXX-env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 14, in get_wsgi_application
[Thu Sep 10 16:09:43.900652 2015] [:error] [pid 7503] [remote XXX]     django.setup()
[Thu Sep 10 16:09:43.900694 2015] [:error] [pid 7503] [remote XXX]   File "XXX/XXX-env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
[Thu Sep 10 16:09:43.900753 2015] [:error] [pid 7503] [remote XXX]     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
[Thu Sep 10 16:09:43.900781 2015] [:error] [pid 7503] [remote XXX]   File "XXX/XXX-env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 78, in populate
[Thu Sep 10 16:09:43.900878 2015] [:error] [pid 7503] [remote XXX]     raise RuntimeError("populate() isn't reentrant")
[Thu Sep 10 16:09:43.900961 2015] [:error] [pid 7503] [remote XXX] RuntimeError: populate() isn't reentrant
```

Comment: without any code or error this is nearly impossible

Comment: Are you running the built-in dev web server?  Do you see any errors in its output?

Comment: @LawrenceBenson Now with more code. If anything else can be useful just let me know and I'll happily provide it to you.

Comment: @trpt4him Nope, I am running on Apache. I have been using Apache for a couple of days now and before erasing the SQLite3 file it was working marvellous.

Comment: maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26324343/upgrade-to-django-1-7-appregistrynotready-exception) can help?

Comment: or at least something similar to it...?

Comment: @LawrenceBenson It doesn't seem to be related, even though the error logs appear very similar.

Comment: Did you try just restarting Apache?

Comment: @trpt4him Many times.

Comment: @SecretParrot I think this one has answer for your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27093746/django-stops-working-with-runtimeerror-populate-isnt-reentrant

Comment: @tevinjoseph No, as I said I restarted Apache already and it had no effect. :(

Comment: Did you change permissions or directory structures?  Is `XXX/api/wsgi.py` accessible by the Apache user?

Comment: @trpt4him It is. Also, why changing database would result in a permission problem?

Comment: Just trying to make suggestions based on what I see in the logs.  In that earliest error it seems to be fussing about the file itself, so I thought it worth it to check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally managed to solve this. The problem was caused by the fact I had the wrong version of WSGI. In order to use WSGI with Python 3.4 mod_WSGI 4.2+ is required.

(I still don't know why the problem began when I erased the db.sqlite3 file.)

See [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569550/assertionerror-using-apache2-and-libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3-on-ubuntu-14-04-python) for more details. I follow [samb](https://askubuntu.com/users/30535/samb)'s step-by-step guide and it worked for me.